# Add space to vertically centered bootstrap 4 cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a margin between the cards in the middle column as is done on the cards in the right and left columns. Adding margin top and/or margin bottom to the card class did not work. Neither did adding a return. The only thing that came close was an hr, but that gives a vertical line on either side of the cards as you can see. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">Taller</h2>
                <h4 class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</h4>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default-drk">Link To</a>
         </div>
<hr>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">Taller</h2>
                <h4 class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</h4>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default-drk">Link To</a>
         </div>
<hr>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">Taller</h2>
                <h4 class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</h4>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default-drk">Link To</a>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
        <div class="card card-body mb-3">Center</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't closing some "Taller" divs. Once you close that and you add the "mb-3" class to the cards, the problem is solved.

```
<div class="card mb-3">
     <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Taller</h2>
            <h4 class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</h4>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default-drk">Link To</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Taller</h2>
            <h4 class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</h4>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default-drk">Link To</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">Taller</h2>
            <h4 class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</h4>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default-drk">Link To</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When put into the entire container makeup with the other two columns this solution doesn't work.